# jQuery conditional addClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

Having a little hang up with jQuery addClass. I have a #story div in my markup that shrinks down when it acquires the "away" class, and then pops back up when it looses that class.

Here's the snag:

```
$('#story div.x').on('click', function () {
  if (!$('#story').hasClass('away')) {
    $('#story').addClass('away');
  }
});
```

The code above simply adds a blank class="" to my story element, but...

```
$('#story div.x').on('click', function () {
  if (!$('#story').hasClass('away')) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#story').addClass('away');
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

That code adds the appropriate class="away" attribute.

What gives?

Comment: Are you updating the classes of the `#story` element somewhere else?

Comment: Following up on Alexander's question: Might there be another click event handler, being called after the one you've posted here, that is clearing the class? You can test this quickly by returning `false` from the "click" event handler function.

Comment: @Mathletics, that code works different than the one OP is using

Comment: @Alexander you're right; it's only going one way. oops!

Comment: @Costa, Just to be clear, the code you posted works as expected. It's better if you provide more information

Comment: @Mathletics, actually if he wants to simplify it, it's a matter of removing the conditional

Comment: You guys are right on, there's propagation going on. The #story element has a click handler that reverses the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there is another event updating the class, or perhaps the element is not yet ready but becomes available after 1 second, perhaps after an ajax call or when the DOM is ready.

Could that be it?